# Serverless GitHub Action: Serverless not found

Tags: node.js, github-actions, serverless

Just started playing around with the Serverless GitHub Action (https://github.com/serverless/github-action). I have a few plugins in the config file, so need to follow their guidance availabe in the [README](https://github.com/serverless/github-action#usage-with-serverless-plugins). However, I am getting a `serverless not found` error. I have already opened an [issue](https://github.com/serverless/github-action/issues/83) but no response yet, so thought this would be my next community to ask from.

Config file:

```
name: Deploy main branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - name: serverless deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@v3.2
      with:
        args: -c "cd backend/endpoints && \
                  serverless plugin install -n serverless-deployment-bucket && \
                  serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements && \
                  serverless plugin install -n serverless-iam-roles-per-function && \
                  serverless plugin install -n serverless-offline && \
                  serverless deploy"
        entrypoint: /bin/sh
      env:
        SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

But get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1:  serverless: not found
```

Not sure what exactly needs to be in the `package.json` file? I added `serverless` as a dep but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;Dr**

Prefix the serverless command with the npm execution command (ref: [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx/))

```
npx serverless plugin install [...]
```

**Explanation**

It looks like the shell is not able to find the command after you installed it as a dependency.

This is due to the fact that locally installed dependencies do not provide cli commands out of their installation context. That's also why you will find command line tools always having the "-g" flag set in their installation instructions.

To make use of a locally installed arbitrary command, you will have to use the execution library that ships with the package manager ([npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx/)).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue resolved by simply installing serverless globally before deployment command.

Workflow file:

```yaml
name: CI (Push)

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, cs_cancellation]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Setup the node js environment on runner instance
      - name: Set up Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "18.x"

      # Install required project dependencies on runner for smooth deployment
      - name: Install dependencies
        id: install-dependencies
        uses: ./.github/install-dependencies

      # Configure the aws-cli on runner instance
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1

      # Build and deploy the lambda functions packages
      - name: Build and deploy lambda
        id: build-and-deploy-lambda
        uses: ./.github/deploy-packages
        with:
          lambda-function: ${{ matrix.lambda-function }}
          environment-name: stage
```

Dependency file:

```yaml
name: Install Dependencies
description: Install required project dependencies
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
      with:
        version: 8

    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 18.x

    - name: Install serverless
      run: pnpm install -g serverless
      shell: bash

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: pnpm install
      shell: bash
```